# Best Practice Tips upgrade Win server 2010 to Server 2012 R2 along with SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, best-practices, windows-server

I have installed SharePoint 2010 in Windows server 2008 and i want to migrate to Windows server 2012 R2
Suggest any Pre-Cure step for Preventing from crash?

- I have All site collection backup from central Admin

**Update** : SharePoint 2010 not supported in Win. server 2012, but SharePoint 2010 SP2 configuration supported ,but it also have some limitaion like it's not supported Windows in-place upgrade for this scenario.

Comment: Only database migration or database with SharePoint to 2013?

Comment: Database with SharePoint But not in sharepoint 2013 , It just server OS Migrating 2008 to 2013@AtishDipongkor

Comment: Do you want upgrade os of sharepoint server or sql server also? How many server in farm?

Comment: only OS of SharePoint server not SQL server @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Answer (score 2):

You have to uninstall sharepoint, upgrade os and reinstall the sharepoint with exact version.

To perform a full-version operating system upgrade on a SharePoint Server 2010 or SharePoint Server 2013 server, follow these steps:
Make sure that the intended operating system is supported by the version of SharePoint that you are running.

- Detach the content databases from the SharePoint server.
- Uninstall SharePoint through Control Panel.
- Upgrade the operating system.
- Reinstall SharePoint
- Attach the content databases

Here is the reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2818510

But if you have one more server which you can use for temp purpose then this will be even safe.