# Farm backup and restore from windows server 2008 R2 to windows server 2012 R2 in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, backup, restore

Can we do farm backup(from Central Admin) of sharepoint 2013 in Windows server 2008 R2 and restore the entire farm to Windows server 2012 R2?

Comment: Related (or duplicate, if you are doing the OS upgrade for the same environment): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184308/best-practice-tips-upgrade-win-server-2010-to-server-2012-r2-along-with-sp2010

Comment: we are upgrading OS of SQL Server from 2008 r2 to 2012 r2 tooo and both sql server and webapp server upgrades are not in place upgrades

Comment: Such information could be handy to have available in the original question. Anyway, as the link I gave suggests, SharePoint's migration to another OS environment is possible. I have done it without too much concentrating in the changing versions but more on the actual restore of backup process. I believe Microsoft's documentation doesn't have a case exact like yours, but combining available pieces you could have them assisting you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is possible , but it is not recommend to do it if this is production environment .
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/794ec936-60a0-4b36-a213-4e56808858fb/sharepoint-2013-server-os-upgrade-from-windows-2008-r2-to-windows-2012-r2?forum=sharepointadmin ,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/17/upgrading-an-existing-sharepoint-2013-farm-to-windows-server-2012-r2/ .

See the best practices when you want to do backup and restore :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384.aspx ;

Answer (score 1):

I would never backup and restore the farm. Best practice is to
1. Build new farm. 
2. Install all wsps you use in source (if you don't have them in source control you can backup them from the source farm) 
3. Migrate content databases and services databases (if required) to the new farm.

Comment: Will the custom master page, .js files be restored in new server if we migrate content database

Comment: No master page that should be part of your wsps. If you strore js file in site collection they will move over. If they were deployed using wsp then it is same situation as with master page.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is another reason beyond upgrading the OS, I would just add the 2012 R2 servers to your farm, transition services over to those servers, then remove the 2008 R2 servers from the farm.

On the SQL side, you can either add the databases to a SQL Mirroring session and failover to a new edition of OS + SQL, or simply use a SQL alias on the SharePoint servers (new and old) to point to the new SQL server.